# RegEx to allow 12 or 13 digits

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application I define validation using the following RegEx

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{8}0[1-2]\d{3}", ErrorMessage = "Must be numeric, 12 or 13 characters long & Format xxxxxxxx[01 or 02]xxx")]
```

But I want to allow 12 or 13 characters. The `d{3}` appears to be forcing that overall I have 13 characters input

To allow it to accept 12 or 13, I have changed `d{3}` to `d{2}` and its accepting 12 now.

But - can I be sure it will still take 13 characters?

Comment: Why not just `\d{12,13}`

Comment: You can use `\d{2, 3}` (allows 2 or 3 of the preceding character)

Comment: Try this one:  \d{8}0[1-2]\d{2,3}

Comment: why are you requesting 12 or 13, just make it 13 because 12 under it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Must be numeric, 12 or 13 characters long & Format xxxxxxxx[01 or 02]xxx

To allow digits `1` or `2` after first nine digits,

```
^\d{8}0[12]\d{2,3}$
       ^^^^         : Allow 1 or 2 after `0`
           ^^^^^^^  : Any two or three digits
```

Note that `[12]` can also be written as `(1|2)` using OR/alteration.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pJ1qY0/3)